# Issues with Autopilot on 14.04.3

Tags: apt, ppa, maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm following the steps from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot for autopilot install. This was working about a week ago on 14.04.3 and I'm not doing anything different then what I was doing a week ago.

After adding the ppa stable repos and after issuing the `sudo apt-get update` command, it fails to install MAAS with `sudo apt install maas`

error is:

```
sudo apt install maas
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 maas : Depends: maas-region-controller (= 1.8.3+bzr4053-0ubuntu1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know if this has changed for 14.04.3? It works for 15.10 but I'm trying to stay with a LTS release.

I've tried to show held packages and tried to install maas-region-controller and other dependencies it complains about but still does not work.

Has anyone else experienced this / Has anything changed with the PPA's?

Comment: Can you run "apt-cache policy maas maas-region-controller" and share the output please?

Comment: There seems to be a character limit in here so please see below on the answers section for the results of "apt-cache policy maas maas-region-controller" - If someone know's how to move it up in this section please do.

Comment: Ok that looks as I'd expect, can you retry the apt install, if it fails again, please try "sudo apt install maas-region-controller" first and include any error output here

Comment: Ok so I've ran through that now, and again it was too may chars to post up here. Please see the answers section below for the results.

Comment: Please paste the results of "apt-cache policy python-django" using pastebin.ubuntu.com (this will avoid the character limit) - note that you shouldn't expect python-django16 to be installable on Trusty, hence the Depends line is          python-django16 | python-django (<< 1.7), I think perhaps you're getting python-django from somewhere else (another PPA?) that is later than the one in Trusty proper

Comment: @AdamCollard Please see the output of apt-cache policy python-django. I have added the juju/stable, maas/stable & cloud-installer/stable ppa's as per the autopilot installation instructions. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14077725/

Comment: I just did a reinstall as the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot have been updated. They added in "sudo apt-get install python-software-properties". After all that, it still fails at sudo apt-get install maas with the same issue.

Comment: Can you try one more time? Alerted my colleagues to this issue (thank you for taking the time to respond on here) and we believe it to be fixed

Comment: @AdamCollard Just tried it again and now it's working. Thanks for working on fixing this!

Answer (score 1):

This was an intermittent issue due to an erroneous upload of `python-django` to the [Cloud installer PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/cloud-installer/stable) which has subsequently been resolved.